# How to train pre trained model (MNIST) tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I have a project with Fashion MNIST, which predicts clothes from uploaded images, and I want to make some improvements with it. Is it possible to modify my project that it will train automatically after each uploaded and prediction?

Comment: Hi @SembeiNorimaki, thank you for your comment! I just want to minimize incorrect predictions count in my projects, so I just want to find some solutions for that

Comment: What is your project? Is it a deep net or a SVM or Regression model?

Comment: Good news: you can. Bad news: it's called _Online Learning_. Good luck googling that!

Comment: Better news: it's also called [_Incremental Learning_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_learning).

Answer (score 0):

You can train your model manually by using the transfer learning technique(Transfer learning is a method of reusing an already trained model for another task).

1. Instantiate a base model and load pre-trained weights into it.
2. Freeze all layers in the base model by setting trainable = False.
3. Create a new model on top of the output of one (or several) layers
   from the base model. Train your new model on your new dataset.

Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/b906dd5ebb58006149986c7dffd862a2) for working code example. Thank You.